# Script using multiprocess with queue does not exit after done

Tags: queue, deadlock, exit, multiprocess

I made a script using multiprocess with queue.
When the script done, it still remains not exit.
I checked similar cases in stackoverflow and tried solutions, but failed.

Would you kindly review my script and give some advices?

```
import multiprocessing
import Settings
import Investigation
import Mailing
import queue
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, Manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
freeze_support()
Settings.Init()

mgr = Manager()
shared_Q = mgr.Queue()

KOSDAQ_P = Process(target=Investigation.Searching, args=(shared_Q, 35, 1, 3))  #30, 2))    
KOSPI_P = Process(target=Investigation.Searching, args=(shared_Q, 19, 1, 3))     

KOSDAQ_P.daemon = True
KOSPI_P.daemon = True

KOSDAQ_P.start()
KOSPI_P.start()

while True:
    try:
        Data = shared_Q.get_nowait()
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('A' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[0]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('A' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Interior.ColorIndex = Data[1]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('B' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[2]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('C' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[7]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('D' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[6]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('E' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[5]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('F' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[4]
        Settings.Today_result_sheet.Range('G' + str(Settings.Report_Y)).Value = Data[3]
        Settings.Report_Y += 1
    except queue.Empty:
        break

KOSPI_P.join()
KOSDAQ_P.join()

Mailing.Mailing_to_me()
```

Comment: Typically you also do a `close()` on a process after the `join()`.

Comment: I added join() after join(), but still doesn't close properly.  (KOSPI_P.close(), KOSDAQ_P.close())   Alas....

Comment: And you want them to be daemon processes?

Comment: Not at all, I just added (deamon = True) because it was one of the solutions in Stackoverflow.  I don't care whether it is deamon or not. I want my script to exit properly after done.

Comment: Do you still see the same issues when you don't include `daemon = True`?

Comment: I deleted (daemon = True) then make EXE. The result is same.... T.T

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue you are seeing with self-contained code, instead of the above?  As is, it's hard to know what the impact of `Settings`, `Investigation` and `Mailing` is.

Comment: I tested with full source code including Settings, Investigation, and Mailing. Python is easy to code, but hassle happens often.

Comment: My point is that if you can produce a self-contained minimal working example of what you are experiencing, it's easier for others to help you as they can run the same code as you, and see the same results.

Comment: I got it. I'll make minimal version and test then add comment.

Comment: Dear Mike, I found the cause of problem due to your advice. I found something wrong with Init(). I change code of Init() and finally I got good result. I appreciate your kind effort. ^.^

Comment: That's excellent news. I'm glad you resolved it. You can also answer your own question here if you like, as it may help others who find this question.